# What is the name of the family of sequences $a_n = f(a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, \ldots)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

1.

Where $a_1$ (the first term) is defined, and an arbitrary number (possibly zero) of successive terms are defined.

All $a_k$ are numbers (could be natural, integer, real, complex, $\ldots$)

Examples include the sequences of [Pell numbers](https://oeis.org/A000129) and [Fibonacci numbers](https://oeis.org/A000045).

Does your answer change depending on the type of number?

2.

Same as (1), except $a_k$ need not be numbers, but could be drawn from any well-defined collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequences satisfies the recurrence relation.

Comment: I think ["recurrence relation"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecurrenceRelation.html) is what I was looking for. Is there a special term when dealing with numbers, or specific sets of numbers (e.g., the integers)?

Comment: integer sequences